# How to check which SMTP client I have installed?

Tags: smtp

How do I check which SMTP client I have installed?  And how do I configure it?

Answer (score 1):

Most email programs, like Thunderbird or Evolution, have a SMTP client build in to send mail, so you can have more than one SMTP client installed and there is no easy way to get a list of all installed clients.

What do you want to do?

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to get a Ruby on Rails send email.  I just want to know what settings to give it so that it will start sending.  Currently I get no errors from Ruby and it is trying to send, but can't :( so I figured I should look into SMTP

Comment: I've never used Ruby on Rails but maybe this helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144510/how-to-check-rails-mail-setting